How many times can you use “to” before verbs?
If a sentence describes a goal, then how many times should “to” be used there?

My goal is to practice conversation and to improve my vocabulary.

Or

My goal is to practice conversation and improve my vocabulary.


When the structure is the same, like yours, you do not need to repeat it.

I like to run, skip, jump, sing and swim. One 'to' for five verbs.

Repeating "to" is optional. Both your examples are correct, with just one and with two-to's (not ballet dresses ;-).

The Preamble of the U.S. Constitution begins sans duplicate prepositions:
"We the People of the United States, in Order to form a more perfect Union, establish Justice, insure domestic Tranquility, provide for the common defense, promote the general Welfare, and secure the Blessings of Liberty...

Alfred Lord Tennyson's Ulysses, though, repeats use of that preposition for emphasis.
"To strive, to seek, to find, and not to yield".


Chacun à son goût, and don't drink too much port wine.

Both of your sentences are correct. There is no rule which limits the number you can use. Use as many as you want.  Go for it!

To be, or not to be, that is the question:
Whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer
The slings and arrows of outrageous fortune,
Or to take Arms against a Sea of troubles,
And by opposing end them: to die, to sleep
No more; and by a sleep, to say we end
The heart-ache, and the thousand natural shocks
That Flesh is heir to? 'Tis a consummation
Devoutly to be wished. To die, to sleep,
To sleep, perchance to Dream; aye, there's the rub,

From Hamlet (Act 3, Scene 1) by William Shakespeare.
Note how one of these is actually a sentence ending in a preposition, and not the infinitive marker "to".
Also note that the example above is poetic, and the most extreme example I could think of. So, it's not like normal prose or speech. There is a tendency in English not to repeat things if we don't have to, to avoid redundancy, but you can choose to repeat them for effect/emphasis if you want.
